# How to extend cassandra SessionManager for Instrumentation

Tags: java, cassandra, driver, datastax

I would like to instrument queries executed via datastax java driver in Cassandra. Is extending com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager is the way? Also if extending SessionManager I have to Instantiate it in com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster by modifying Cluster source too ?
is this the best way or is there any other possible way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I just collect metrics by timing the call to session.execute():

```
private Session session;
private AtomicLongMap<String> executeCount;
private AtomicLongMap<String> executeTime;
```

....

```
@Override
public ResultSet execute(BoundStatement statement, Object... bindVariables) {
    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executeCount.incrementAndGet(command);
        executeTime.addAndGet(command, endTime - startTime);
        return resultSet;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.error("IllegalArgumentException executing:" + command + ":" + Arrays.toString(bindVariables));
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: OTOH, is there info other than timing you want to collect?

Comment: Hi Don, Thanks for the answer. But I think my question is not clear. My main question is, to instrument, we have to extend SessionManager or implement Session interface and how to associate with Cluster class ?.

Comment: Why do you have to extend SessionManager?